# MS SQL SSMS - configuration is incorrect

Tags: sql-server-express

When I try to run Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio 18 on
Windows Server 2019 Essential I get an error like this following

"The application can not be started because its configuration at the same time is incorrect."

REMARK:
This is a translation from Polish:

Question:
Could somebody give a hint on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You have provided an incomplete translation of the error message more than likely.  The complete English translation more than likely is, "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail", can you confirm that fact?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the contents of the application configuration file for SSMS 18.  If you are unable to find that I suggest you instead, upgrade to SSMS 18.1, after you uninstall SSMS 18[.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-its-side-by-side-configuration-is-incorrect-error-related-to-mmc-exe-programs-and-weird-cause-simple-solution/)0

Comment: In the event, you have no idea what the application configuration file is, or how to locate it, run the sxstrace.exe tool against SSMS and provide the results as a screenshot.  You simply run `sxstrace.exe Trace -log file:C:\MySxSTrace.log` then start SSMS.  I won't be able to provide an answer to your question without the application configuration file (`..\SSMS.config`).  This also might be the [error](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/00/57/62/71/sxs-xp4.PNG)

Comment: "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail", 

Yes.

Comment: I am still waiting for the required information I need to submit an answer, I must warn you, the research I did has long been deleted so I might be unable to submit an answer at this point.

Comment: When I try to install or uninstall then I have another problem.
The installation process starts and never ends... it stuck.

Comment: btw. 
I'm a very rare user of this forum,  (I write more often on AutoIt, osTicket, TeamViewer my nickname there is "mLipok") ..... so currently here... I'm wondering how to insert file or screenshot ?

Comment: Also sorry for long delay in my answer, but I have a couple of more problems to solve every single day in my daily basis, and this problem is not so hot as I can still log into SQL using MS SQL Management installed on another workstation, but on the other hand it's annoying when something does not work as it should, so every few days I get back to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you got

```
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.
```

for SSMS and you need to reinstall, this might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/61630911/586754

(Several answers with different options, uninstall, reinstall - if that works, delete manually, ...)